# Properties declared *in* the Constructor are visible in instances. Why?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototype, this

In Javascript’s system of prototypal inheritance, an object’s internal prototype reference is set to its constructor’s “prototype” property, which is itself an object.

Properties of the constructor’s “prototype” property may be resolved as if they were properties of object instances. However, the actual properties of the constructor object are *not* accessible to the instance:

```
function MyConstructor() { }
MyConstructor.x = 3
MyConstructor.prototype.y = 7

a = new MyConstructor()
a.x == 3    // FALSE
a.y == 7    // TRUE
```

However, if the property (“`x`”) of the constructor is declared in the function body with the `this` keyword, these properties *are* of course resolved by instances:

```
function MyConstructor() {
    this.x = 3
}
MyConstructor.prototype.y = 7

a = new MyConstructor()
a.x == 3    // TRUE
```

Why? What is the difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do this:

```
MyConstructor.x = 3;
```

...you've only added a property to the Function object instance referenced by `MyConstructor`. A Function object has many properties that do not become part of the instance (nor would you want them to).

As such, the mechanism for creating instance properties via the constructor is to use the `this.x` method.

When the constructor runs, `this` *is* the object that is being returned. So it is just a convenience so you don't have to do:

```
a = new MyConstructor();
a.x = 3;
a.x == 3    // TRUE!
```

Because `this` in the constructor is the same as the resulting object, there's no need to do it explicitly upon each new instance creation.

The `prototype` object is simply an object that is referenced by all instances of `MyConstructor` so if there isn't a property on the instance, it then goes to the `prototype` to find one.

---

To illustrate the relationship between `this` and the new instance, consider this example:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/M2prR/

```
var test; // will hold a reference to "this"

function MyConstructor() {
    test = this; // make "test" reference "this"
}

   // create a new instance
var inst = new MyConstructor;

   // see if they are the same object. This will alert "true"
alert( inst === test );
```

Comment: Thank you, that’s v clear. `this` refers to the instance being created, not the constructor. Obvious in retrospect!

Comment: To verify: `a.hasOwnProperty('x')  // => TRUE` (Confirms that `x` is a property of `a`, and not being retrieved by following the prototype chain.)

Comment: @Benji XVI: You're welcome. I added an example that illustrates it further.